# How do instance variables in rspec work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, instance-variables

Here is a bit of code from M Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial. Can anyone explain why an instance variable (@user) is necessary and why not use a local variable. Also, since instance variables are supposed to be the variables in the instance of a class, which class is @user instantiated from?

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before { @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com") }

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
end
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use of a local variable in that instance would mean that its scope would be restricted to the `before` and hence result in an error. The `@user` is of type User but is an instance variable of the `describe` block. Rspec has some magic that at run-time makes a class out of each `describe` block. Each example (`it` block) ends up being a subclass of said class. Class inheritance lets the examples see `@user`.

**Edited 2017-05-14**

Linked blog post is no longer available. Updating with Wayback Machine link + inlining relevant section here.

Note that this is considered an anti-pattern as detailed in this [blog post](http://bitfluxx.com/2011/05/23/some-rspec-tips-and-best-practices.html). Use `let` instead.

`let` has the following advantages:

- It is memoized when used multiple times in one example, but not
  across examples.
- It is lazy-loaded, so you wont waste time initializing the variable for examples that don't reference it.
- Will raise an exception if you have a typo in your variable name.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now. I always thought describe block was used to make the tests more readable to humans and nothing else. Thanks :)

Comment: That blog post is no longer available. It might be worth updating the answer to include reasons why using an instance variable is an antipattern and remove the broken link.

Answer (score 12):

You can't use a local variable because a local variable exists only in the scope of the local method. `before`, `subject` and `it` generates different scopes within the same class.

The following code

```
before { user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com") }
```

will raise an undefined variable when you call it in

```
subject { user }
```

The instance `@user` is an instance of the class `User` (after all, you create it with `User.new`).

However, instead of instance variables you might want to use the `let` command. Also, if you define

```
subject { User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com") }
```

the use of `before` is not required. You'll also get the extra benefit to get a `subject` method available to access the instance, equal to define `let(:subject)`.

Comment: +1 on using `let`: `let(:user) { User.create(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com") }`

Comment: +1 on using subject: subject { User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com") }

Answer (score 2):

`subject` ad `it` blocks are under different scopes, so local variables won't work. `@user` belongs to class generated by RSpec under the hood.