# Ruby on Rails RSpec Compare Function Values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have two function values that I'm trying to compare and make sure one is greater than the other, and I just cannot figure out how to do it in RSpec. One function is "uncompleted_tasks" and the other is "tasks.count", both of which are part of a User model. Here is what I have in RSpec. The subject is an instance of the User model and RSpec gives me the error, "undefined local variable or method 'ut' for # (NameError)", on the line "expect(ut).should be <= tc". What's going on?

```
describe "uncompleted tasks should be less than or equal to total task count" do
    before do
        ut = subject.uncompleted_tasks
        tc = subject.tasks.count
    end
    expect(ut).should be <= tc
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645198/how-do-instance-variables-in-rspec-work) for further details, but basically local variables in RSpec are limited to their local scope, including `before` blocks.  So, the variables defined in your `before` block aren't available in the test.  I'd suggest using instance variables for this:

```
describe "uncompleted tasks" do
  before do
      @ut = subject.uncompleted_task
      @tc = subject.tasks.count
  end

  it "should be less than or equal to total task count" do
    expect(@ut).should be <= @tc
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use instance variables and your expect needs to be inside an it block.  Like below:

```
describe "uncompleted tasks should be less than or equal to total task count" do
    before do
        @ut = subject.uncompleted_tasks
        @tc = subject.tasks.count
    end
    it "something" do
      expect(@ut).should be <= @tc
    end
end
```